# Saving pandas excel dataframe with dynamic filename

Tags: file, variables, pandas, export-to-excel, filepath

I am trying to save a dataframe to Excel and unfortunately I am not getting around the Syntax.
I want to save the file to a path and Name it by today date.

```
df.to_excel(r'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente\'',today.strftime("%d%m%Y")+'delmedf.xlsx')
```

Am I doing something wrong with the quote signs?

Comment: You can try change `,` to `+` like `df.to_excel(r'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente\' + today.strftime("%d%m%Y")+'delmedf.xlsx')`, because you concanecate strings.

Comment: this works now, but I am getting a `'` in front of the filename.  `'25022016delmedf.xlsx`

Comment: Try remove one `'` in the end of `'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente\'`

Comment: removal of one `'` results in `invalid Syntax`

Comment: please check `df.to_excel(r'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente\'' + dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")+'delmedf.xlsx')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try add `()` to `today` and `+` before:

```
import datetime as dt

print dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")
25022016

df.to_excel(r'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente\\' + dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")+'delmedf.xlsx')
```

Comment: I Keep getting the ` '` in front of the filename. `'25022016delmedf.xlsx`.  I am not sure if this is some problem of how to set the backslashes and quotations?

Comment: Yes, I see it - try modified solution.

Comment: awesome! This is working now. Thanks a lot. The Setting of this backslashes is really a bit odd...

Comment: And maybe I found better solution `df.to_excel(r'\\folderA\folderB\Dokumente' + '\\'  + dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y")+'delmedf.xlsx')`